# I need powerful interactive packet manipulation program like scapy

Tags: python, ruby, packet, scapy

I need powerful interactive packet manipulation program like [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)  for Ruby

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Scruby ? http://www.rubyinside.com/scruby-a-ruby-shell-for-packet-sending-and-sniffing-460.html

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/ahobson/ruby-pcap

here's one. Don't know how powerful it when compared to Scapy, but it was enough for my needs.